# How to set up opengl/glut for programming in XCode on snow leopard?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

How can I configure my snow leopard environment to begin programming with OpenGL and GLUT?  Are there nice macports available that will set it all up for me?  And how does it link with XCode?

Thanks for the help.  Just getting started with using XCode for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is include the OpenGL and GLUT frameworks in your project and then use `#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>` and `#include <GLUT/glut.h>` to access them.

Of course you have forgotten to state which version of Xcode you are using so it is hard to give specific help as Xcode 3.x and Xcode 4.x are significantly different from each other.